# Representing Nested Models as an SKLearn Pipeline

Tags: machine-learning, python, predictive-models, dataset, scikit-learn

**Goal:** Represent nested models with SKLearn's Pipeline / ColumnTransformer / FeatureUnion setup.

**Specific issue:** I cannot figure out how to use the prediction from one model as a factor of a secondary model.

**Example of what I don't know how to do:**
Let $W_1, W_2, X_1, X_2$ be features. Let $Y$ represent the target variable. Assume $W_i$ and $X_i$ are already preprocessed and well behaved.

1. Use Ridge to regress $Y$ on $W_1$, $W_2$. Let $\hat{Y}_W$ be the output from this step
2. Use Ridge to regress $Y$ on $X_1$, $X_2$. Let $\hat{Y}_X$ be the output from this step
3. Use XGBRegressor to regress $Y$ on $\hat{Y}_W$, $\hat{Y}_X$

**Example of what I know how to do:**
In the below example instead of using Ridge I use PCA as an intermediate step. I believe this works because PCA implements `.fit` and `.transform`. However, `Ridge`, or other estimator classes implement `.fit` and `.predict` (i.e. they do not implement `.transform`).

1. Use PCA on $W_1$, $W_2$ and retrieve a single principle component factor. Let $\hat{PCA1}_W$ be the output from this step
2. Use PCA on $X_1$, $X_2$ and retrieve a single principle component factor. Let $\hat{PCA1}_X$ be the output from this step
3. Use Linear Regression to regress $Y$ on $\hat{PCA1}_W$, $\hat{PCA1}_X$

````py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

w1 = [x for x in range(10)]
w2 = [x ** 2 for x in range(10)]
x1 = [-x for x in range(10)]
x2 = [2*x for x in range(10)]
y = [x + 2 for x in range(10)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'w1': w1, 'w2': w2, 'x1': x1, 'x2': x2, 'y': y})

pca_transformer = ColumnTransformer(
    [
        ("pca_w", PCA(n_components=1), ['w1', 'w2']),
        ("pca_x", PCA(n_components=1), ['x1', 'x2']),
    ]
)

pipeline = Pipeline(
    [
        ("pca_transformer", pca_transformer),
        ("model", LinearRegression())
    ]
)

cross_val_score(estimator=pipeline,
                X=df,
                y=df['y'],
                scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',
                cv=10).mean()
```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You predict values and then use those values as if they were features. Am I missing something?

Comment: Apologies for the vagueness of the initial question. I've added significant detail. @Dave this is trivially done in pandas or generally outside of the pipeline / column transformer schema but I am specifically looking to do this in the pipeline setup and am failing to see the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hack to achieve what I am looking for. Specifically, add `transform` to the regression estimator directly.

It is relatively lightweight but somewhat disheartening that I can't find an out-of-the-box solution for this pattern.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

w1 = [x for x in range(10)]
w2 = [x ** 2 for x in range(10)]
x1 = [-x for x in range(10)]
x2 = [2*x for x in range(10)]
y = [x + 2 for x in range(10)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'w1': w1, 'w2': w2, 'x1': x1, 'x2': x2, 'y': y})

def generic_transform(self, X):
    return self.predict(X=X).reshape(-1, 1)
LinearRegression.transform = generic_transform


lr_transformer = ColumnTransformer(
    [
        ("lr_w", LinearRegression(), ['w1', 'w2']),
        ("lr_x", LinearRegression(), ['x1', 'x2']),
    ]
)

pipeline = Pipeline(
    [
        ("lr_transformer", lr_transformer),
        ("model", LinearRegression())
    ]
)

cross_val_score(estimator=pipeline,
                X=df,
                y=df['y'],
                scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',
                cv=10).mean()
```

Comment: The better answer here is StackingRegressor: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.StackingRegressor.html